# ASP.NET AJAX GUI Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, coolite

Anybody worked with Coolite toolkit?

How to add a Coolite child control in a Coolite window?

In ASP.NET(C#) of course!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the controls in the `<Body>` element. Here is an example of a window with an accordion panel and in the first panel there is a color picker.

```
<ext:Window ID="Window1" runat="server" Title="Child Control Test" Height="300px"
    Width="500px" BodyStyle="padding: 6px; background-color: #fff;" Collapsible="True"
    Modal="True" Icon="Application">
    <Body>
        <ext:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" Animate="true">
            <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Border="false" Title="Item 1">
                <Body>
                Panel 1 Content
                <ext:ColorPalette ID="ColorPalette1" runat="server" Width="400" Height="200"></ext:ColorPalette>
                </Body>
            </ext:Panel>
            <ext:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Border="false" Collapsed="true" Title="Item 2">
                <Body>
                Panel 2 Content
                </Body>
            </ext:Panel>
        </ext:Accordion>
    </Body>
</ext:Window>
```

**Here is a screen shot of the result:**

[Coolite Window with Child Controls http://ryanscook.com/Files/CoolliteChildControl-screen1.jpg](http://ryanscook.com/Files/CoolliteChildControl-screen1.jpg)

Comment: Good answer Ryan! I also need to add controls at dynamically.

Comment: @Ismail, I have marked it. @Ryan, can you please give another hand? Coz, at this moment you seem to be the only person to know Coolite.